# What is the best way to convert C# project files to Objective C classes

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I have a project in C#. I need to convert that C# project classes to Objective C classes. Is there is any good converter to achieve this? Better if there is a full project converter rather than single classes. I know it will not be 100% perfect but still i need to convert at-least 90% of those.

https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/ - This is good for converting Java files to Objective C. But i need figure out how can i convert C# to objective c classes.

Comment: I was curious about this myself: https://varycode.com/converter.html. You can use this as a reference, always make sure you check the code for correctness.

Comment: @JaredBurrows -  varycode won't converts C# to 'Objective C'. Its better if we find anything similar to https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/ in C#

Comment: I provided it as a reference. It only does some of what you asked. You really need to learn and make sure you can do the rest of the code conversion yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 100% answer but I'd like to refer you to [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/161265-to-objective-translator.html), it's a bit dated but has  some interesting discussions surrounding C# -> Objective-C.

Comment: Seems to be a dead link :(